# Backup of Queue manager (saveqmgr or dmpmqcfg)

Tags: ibm-mq

Can any one tell me how to exclude system objects while taking backup of queue manager using save queue manager and dump queue manager commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get "saveqmgr -s" function using "dmpmqcfg" in IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073230/how-to-get-saveqmgr-s-function-using-dmpmqcfg-in-ibm-mq)

Comment: Note the link above from my close vote shows a way to  filter out the objects.   As suggested by @T.Rob it as a good idea to take a separate backup of authority records as stated without filters since you may be giving permission to model queues or other SYSTEM queues.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool that you can used instead of `saveqmgr` or `dmpmqcfg` which can exclude `SYSTEM.*` objects when making a backup of all your queue manager object definitions is MO71.

[image: MO71 QMgr Export configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it is a bad idea to exclude SYSTEM.* objects.  You might have particular values used for SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE, SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN, etc... that may be important when rebuilding a queue manager.

You could write a simple shell script or batch file to copy all objects to a new MQSC file but exclude ones like SYSTEM.ADMIN.*, SYSTEM.AUTH.DATA.QUEUE, etc...

Answer (score 0):

No easy way to tell `dmpmqcfg` to exclude the `SYSTEM.*` objects. You could issue the command multiple times to include all your other object prefixes, but it would be easier to simple delete the `SYSTEM.*` objects from the output produced.